# React Native how to make an unread message function?

Tags: react-native

I need to make an unread message function with react native .
The idea is : the "unread" will just appear one time ,and after the user click the view ,the "unread" will not appear more .. like as follow :
[image]

I attach my code also ,please help me to take a look ,thank you so much !!!

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View,Text } from 'react-native';


function TryMessageScreen(props) {
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <View style={styles.second_container}>
               <Text>Unread</Text>
            </View>  
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,
        justifyContent : "center",
        alignItems : 'center',
    },
    second_container : {
        width : 200,
        height : 100,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        borderWidth : 1,
        borderColor : "#000000",

    }
})
export default TryMessageScreen;
```

Comment: use `useState` hook

Comment: Hi Leri ,thanks so much for your suggestion .Hmm ,useState did work for one time .. However ,next time when you reboot the app ,will appear unRead again .. I need it like the function of our message in social media normally ,normally ,when you have read the message ,it more appear more the unRead notice .. I know another hook which names useEffect .But I have no idea how to use it ..Do you have idea about it ?

Comment: You can use Asyncstorage for this. Otherwise each time you open the app, the value will be reset to the initial one.

Comment: Hi Aswin ,Ok great , I got it .Thank you so much for your tip !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook to keep track whether it is clicked. It it is not clicked yet(`unRead` is false), then show the button:

**Update**: You can use [Async Storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/) to persist. So, first read from local storage, and then plan accordingly:

```
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <TryMessageScreen />
    </>
  );
}

const getReadStatus = async () => {
  let isRead = null;
  try {
    isRead = await AsyncStorage.getItem('read');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return isRead;
};

const setReadToFalse = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('read', JSON.stringify(false));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

function TryMessageScreen(props) {
  const [unRead, setUnRead] = useState(() => getReadStatus || false);

  return (
    <>
      {unRead && (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.second_container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={async () => {
                await setReadToFalse();
                setUnRead(false);
              }}
            >
              <Text>Unread</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Shivam ,thanks so much for your suggestion .Hmm ,useState did work for one time .. However ,next time when you reboot the app ,will appear unRead again .. I need it like the function of our message in social media  ,normally ,when you have read the message ,it won't appear more the unRead notice .. I know another hook which names useEffect .But I have no idea how to use it ..Do you have idea about it ?

Comment: HI Yellow. You can use [Async Storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/) to persist. So, first read from local storage, and then plan accordingly

Comment: Hi Shivam ,Thank you so much !! I will follow your suggestion .Thanks for your kindness my friend !

Comment: @YellowClock I have updated my answer. You can reference from there. Happy to help! 

Comment: That's really awesome !! Thank you so much bro !!!!